# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que todos mis elementos carguen al mismo tiempo con setTimeout?

Tags: javascript

¿Cómo puedo hacer que varios elementos (3 en especifico) de cifras numéricas carguen al mismo tiempo (terminen por ejemplo, juntos, en 4 segundos) es decir, que todos terminen de contar (o aumentar) en 4 segundos con setTimeout en JavaScript.

Ya trate de hacerlo poniéndole decimales pero no funciona.
Gracias

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let scrollHeight = window.pageYOffset;
    if(scrollHeight == 1020){
        const products = document.querySelector('.product .cifras-block-container');
        const sales = document.querySelector('.sales .cifras-block-container');
        const alternative = document.querySelector('.alternative .cifras-block-container');

        if(products.querySelector('span').textContent.replace(",","") == 30000)
        {
            timeOutAnimation(products, 30000, 0.1);
        }
        
        if(sales.querySelector('span').textContent.replace(",","") == 3500)
        {
            timeOutAnimation(sales, 3500, 0.8);
        }
        
        if(alternative.querySelector('span').textContent.replace(",","") == 181)
        {
            timeOutAnimation(alternative, 181, 12.4223602484472);
        }
    }
})

function timeOutAnimation(b, l, t,o=0)
{
        if(o < l){
            b.querySelector('span').textContent = ++o;
            setTimeout(timeOutAnimation,t,b,l,t,o);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No hay forma de garantizar que todos terminen al mismo tiempo, porque *Javascript* no maneja el *setTimeout* con tiempo exacto, pues cada "evento" es enviado a la [*cola de procesamiento*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) y, en cada iteración, revisa si **ya pasó el intervalo** especificado para ejecutarlo.

En teoría, el tiempo mínimo "real" para *setTimeout* es de 4 milisegundos, según la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout), sin embargo, en algún lado (que no recuerdo ahora) leí que para que sea efectivo, debe ser entre **30 y 50 milisegundos**.

Entonces, teniendo en cuenta que **solo se permiten enteros** y que hay tiempos específicos para ejecutar *setTimeout* de forma *"efectiva"*, la opción para que todos tus elementos lleguen al valor deseado "al mismo tiempo" es que todos ejecuten la misma cantidad de iteraciones y definir el incremento que deben tener en cada una:

```js
// Definir constantes globales
// Tiempo máximo, 4 segundos
const maxTime = 4000;
// El tiempo para cada iteración
const delay = 100;

/* window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let scrollHeight = window.pageYOffset;
    if(scrollHeight == 1020) { // */
        const products = document.querySelector('.product .cifras-block-container');
        const sales = document.querySelector('.sales .cifras-block-container');
        const alternative = document.querySelector('.alternative .cifras-block-container');

        // Iniciar animaciones con parseInt para asegurar que es entero o cero, si está vacío
        startAnimation(products, parseInt(products.querySelector('span').textContent.replace(",","")) || 0);
        startAnimation(sales, parseInt(sales.querySelector('span').textContent.replace(",","")) || 0);
        startAnimation(alternative, parseInt(alternative.querySelector('span').textContent.replace(",","")) || 0);
/*    }
}); // */

function startAnimation(element, value) {
    // No ejecutar si el elemento o valor son "falsey"
    if(!element || !value) {
        return;
    }
    // Definir incremento para cada iteración
    const plus = Math.ceil(value / (maxTime / delay));
    // Iniciar animación
    timeOutAnimation(element, value, delay, plus);
}

function timeOutAnimation(element, value, delay, plus, current = 0) {
    current += plus;
    if(current < value) {
        element.querySelector('span').textContent = current;
    setTimeout(timeOutAnimation, delay, element, value, delay, plus, current);
    } else {
        // Asegurar valor final
        element.querySelector('span').textContent = value;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="product"><div class="cifras-block-container"><span>30,000</span></div></div>
<div class="sales"><div class="cifras-block-container"><span>3,500</span></div></div>
<div class="alternative"><div class="cifras-block-container"><span>181</span></div></div>
```

**Notas:**

- Comenté las líneas referentes al evento *scroll* para poder probar aquí
- Como puedes ver, a pesar de tener especificado el mismo tiempo, no terminan igual
- Haciendo pruebas desde el *fragmento de código* los mejores resultados los vi aplicando espera de 100 milisegundos, pero dependerá mucho de la diferencia en el valor final de todos los elementos
- Para calcular el incremento estoy usando `ceil()` porque en las pruebas que hice con `floor()` la diferencia era mayor

Comment: Muchas gracias! Esta respuesta me sirve!

En verdad, gracias. No sé como agradecertelo.